# Simplified syntax to compare last element of list with element before that?

Tags: c#, .net

```
List<DateTime> list = new List<DateTime>();
```

Currently i have the following syntax:

```
if(list[list.Count - 1] != list.[list.Count - 2])
{
    //do something
}
```

This is a incredible long syntax (in my real program the list name is a lot longer as well). The list is also available trough a static method which even increases the width of this syntax by quite a bit.

How can i write this syntax shorter and more readable?

Thanks!

Comment: it's ok like it is. Just check the Count to be at least 2

Comment: Thaknks for the reply, was just wondering if there was a more straight forward way. In my real code the if is like 4 times the length. I still want my code to be readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var count = list.Count; 

if(list[count - 1] != list[count - 2])
{
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make a static Function in that case you will use it from anywhere without creating object

```
if(myclass.PenultimateCondition(mylist))
{
    //do something
}

public class myclass
{
    public static bool PenultimateCondition(List<Datetime> list)
    {
         return list[list.Count - 1] == list.[list.Count - 2];
    }
}
```

**OR**

make datetime extension method. In that case you do not have to even write class name

```
public class ExtensionMethod
{
    public static bool PenultimateCondition(this IEnumerable<DateTime> value)
    {
        Datetime[] dt = value.ToArray();
        return dt[dt.Length-2] == dt[dt.Length-1];
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
if(myList.PenultimateCondition())
{
    //do something
}
```

**OR**

make generic extension method. In that case you can use it for any datatype

```
public class ExtensionMethod
{
    public static bool PenultimateCondition<T>(this IEnumerable<T> value)
    {
        T[] dt = value.ToArray();
        return Equals(dt[dt.Length-2], dt[dt.Length-1]);
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
if(myList.PenultimateCondition())
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: extension method I meant, sorry

Comment: looks better :) However, you can List<DateTime> or IList<DateTime> or even IList<T> ( a generic type). I would use your answer (+1 from me)

Answer (score 1):

Refactor your condition into a function:

```
static Boolean LastTwoElementsAreEqual<T>(IList<T> list) {
  if (list.Count < 2)
    return false;
  return Equals(list[list.Count - 1], list[list.Count - 2]);
}
```

Comment: He wants to know if the last two are not equal, but basic idea holds. Might want to shorten that function name. lol

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest putting it in a method as well, but this is probably the shortest that you could do it in one line:

```
// Mine vs original.
if(list.Last() != list[list.Count - 2])
if(list[list.Count - 1] != list[list.Count - 2])
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use contains function to check the list.

```
String toCheck = list [list.Count - 1]
if(!list.Contains())
{
 // do the ...
}
```

Comment: how this answer responds to the question?

Comment: @AdrianIftode Probably means `if(list[list.Count - 2].Contains(toCheck)`?